# Why are Unicode characters allowed in usernames?

Tags: discussion, users, display-names

I find it to be very informal,
Some names can vary between Japanese letter/words (for example!) or mathematical notations.
It makes it way harder to find these accounts in a simple search.
For a site this big and important, I do not find any reason that people would use
unusual characters which are outside the regular day-to-day ASCII table.

The above is my opinion and I would ask you to respect it as I respect other opinions.

Main point/Question: Why does Stack Exchange allow those names? What was the reason behind this decision? As I said, it makes it harder to use the site and search these people.

I am deeply sorry if I hurt anyone in this thread. You can comment below and I will edit and censor inappropriate words.

Thank you.

Comment: I would edit the question to focus specifically on your concern over how difficult it is to search for names with extended ASCII characters. To call these names bizarre isn't exactly... fair.

Comment: ASCII characters aren't weird: http://www.asciitable.com/ – you're talking about Unicode characters *outside* ASCII.

Comment: I think calling you a racist is an over reaction. The names are superficial, they can be almost anything or duplicates of each other, searching for some users by name is futile. Use the users ID instead.

Comment: @MarkKirby But real talk for a minute.. if you got help from someone and you want to search him again, would you remember in the back of your mind his name or his number? The human brain is much more effective when talking about names to remember! no?

Comment: I know but that is how it works, it is designed that way. It lets you have any user name you want, I think that is worth the inconvenience of the of the ID system. You can also follow and bookmark users questions to make them easier to find.

Answer (score 17):

Stack Exchange is an **international** network, with users from all countries across the world. If a user's real name is Влади́мир Влади́мирович Пу́тин or 习近平, I can imagine they want to use *that* and not some transliteration into Vladimir Vladimirovich Putin resp. Xi Jinping. If you'd join a Russian website, you wouldn't want to be forced to choose your name as ОтправлятьПомощь or СендЧелп, would you?

> As I said, it makes it harder to ... search these people

Why do you want to search these people? The only situation where I want to type a user's name, in chat or when replying to a comment, the autocomplete function will automatically suggest the user's name. If you want to refer to them in an answer because they left a comment and you want to attribute, just copy/paste the name (I do that for long names using the Latin alphabet anyway).

Comment: When checking votes or the people "top X this week" I search some people.. I don't understand why people run away with facts - you cannot search people with unicode, then why implement such thing if you cannot humanely search anyone? I've seem people with only mathematical notations as their name so auto-completion is not working in this situation.. Thank you for your kind answer but I need more explanations!

Comment: You don't need to search them; those links are clickable ...

Comment: @SendHelp One can search for such names. Just because your keyboard layout lacks the respective keys, does not mean that they are absent from everyone else keyboards.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz that is absolutely correct, is it practical? no.. I won't hold any keyboard layout just for this..

Comment: @SendHelp I don't see why you consider this not practical. Let's come back to the example of πάντα ῥεῖ: on mac π is simply alt+p etc. not very difficult to type.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz and windows? and what about arabic / hebrew / mathemtical symbols? you can't say it's that easy

Comment: @SendHelp _"and what about arabic / hebrew / mathemtical symbols?"_  As glorfindel suggested, you can just copy the nicknames and paste it into the search box.

Answer (score 4):

In case you need to search for someone who has helped you before, you can use your inbox or your activity page. You will find any comment or answer coming from that user.

The "Responses" tab on the "Activity" page is very useful. There are several options to list comments, answers or all. As an example, you can find me there from now on.